# How to: several ssh tunnels for http but using sub[1|2].domain.tld in the browser (redirect? proxy?)

Tags: debian, routing, ssh-tunneling

Sry: still looking for the correct title of the question.

i have two ssh (http) tunnels to a remote server. port 8080 and port 3000

`ssh -L 3000:127.0.0.1:3000 -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 user@server`

localy i can access the services/web apps via http localhost:8080 or localhost:3000 using e.g. the firefox browser

but the web applications there are not 100% safe. means: some links linking to the real hostname (eg app1.domain.localdomain (internal lan) and i end up in a "no connection".

i always have to fix the url (on http GET or much more complicated on http POST)

For one http tunnel the firefox proxy setting i can use but not for the other.

What do i have todo that i can call http app1.domain.tld or app2.domain.tld which then uses the tunnels?

while looking for a solution: iptables? if so: how to set temporaily or starting it when open the tunnel?

**update edit, additions:**

when using vpn (other cpu/ work laptop with activ vpn): all works like i want. but on another cpu i dont want all the traffic go through the vpn connection, just that 1,2,3 hosts/ports.

Kind regards

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you have two ssh-tunnels towards the same host? Why? Why do you say 'http' fort the ssh tunnel? Further-on, you talk about an http-tunnel.  It is not really clear what you are doing.

Comment: i updated the question! thx for the hint!

Comment: Consider [`ssh -D`](https://superuser.com/q/1308495/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski can you show the usecase. I read but i dont understand to imaging how to you it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to use some kind of web proxy, and remap `app1.domain.localdomain` to `localhost:8080` etc.

If you can give all the apps that need that a proxy configuration (e.g. via `http_proxy=...` and `https_proxy=...`, or otherwise), you can just run the proxy locally.

Otherwise, you need a "transparent proxy" (google).

There are many proxies you can use, look for similar questions on this site. One option would be `nginx`.

---

That said, if it's *your* web application, it's considered good practice to build it in such a way that you can replace basenames everywhere, if you need tunnels for testing.

Comment: thx for hints. i did that way already, but: too many manual requirements. i have to update the question which is not detailed enough because: when using vpn: all works like i want but not the hole traffic i want to go through the connection then. i think there is a way for 1,2,3 hosts/ports but i dont know how to ask correctly